# Running time complexity

Tags: algorithm, math, time-complexity

For functions f(n) : n! , n^2 and n .. 
If a problem can be solved in 1 second, given that the algorithm to
solve the problem takes f(n)microsecond.

I know for a fact n! = 9 in one second.  but I don't know how this been calculated. Can someone explain to me how these functions were calculated?

Comment: Please frame  the problem in a better way. Nobody will understand what you are asking and you will end up disappointed

Comment: I'm sorry about that my question wasn't about finding the answer it was about why 9 been chosen as f(n!) exactly .. But I know the answer now. Anyways thanks pal for the advise :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I understand, you are being asked "when should I use which", should I use an algorithm that takes a constant time of 1 second? or should I use an algorithm that takes `f(n)` microseconds.

Note that `1 second = 10^6 microseconds`, so you are solving:

f(n) <= 1,000,000
where n is natural.

By assigning f(10), you can see `f(10) = 3,628,800 > 10^6`.

But `f(9) = 362880 < 10^6`

So, for `f(n)=n!`, highest number that you want to use the `f(n)` algorithm is `n=9`.

Do similarly for other candidates and you will get your answer for them as well.

(Hint: solve the equation `f(n) = 10^6`, and have a look what happens in the near proximity of the `n` you found).

Comment: This is what I've been looking for. Thank you very much !